# String index out of bound but dont know where :(

Tags: java, string

Here is my instruction. Im given 2 txt files, one of phone numbers and one of english words. Suppose number 2 to 9 each represents 3 to 4 letters:

```
2 (A B C)
3 (D E F)
4 (G H I)
5 (J K L)
6 (M N O)
7 (P Q R S)
8 (T U V)
9 W X Y Z
```

I'm asked to find the corresponding words for the first 3 numbers, last 4 numbers, and all 7 numbers of each phone number. Sample output:

```
2475463 : AIRLINE
247 : AHR
247 : AHS
247 : AIR
247 : AIS
247 : BIR
247 : BIS
5463 : KIME
5463 : KIND
5463 : LIME
5463 : LIND
5463 : LINE
```

My code compiles and runs well for the last 4 digits and all 7 digits. however, it returns

```
TEL: 2475463
2475463 : AIRLINE
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out     of range: 2
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Lab11.match(Lab11.java:60)
    at Lab11.main(Lab11.java:46)
```

when i include `match(first3[j],listOf3,representation)`.
i know it is trying to tell me an array is out of bound somewhere, 
but i am having a hard time trying to figure out where.
Thank you in advance if you dont get a response. :D

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Lab11{

public static void main(String[] args)
throws FileNotFoundException{

  //First scan to determine # of phone nums
  File nums = new File("telephone.txt");
  int size = arrSize(nums,7,"604 ");

  //Copy nums to array
  //Eliminating 604 and space
  String[] phoneNums = copy(nums,size,7,"604 ");
  String[] first3 = new String[size];
  String[] last4 = new String[size];
  for(int j=0;j<first3.length;j++){
     first3[j] = phoneNums[j].substring(0,2);
  }
  for(int j=0;j<last4.length;j++){
     last4[j] = phoneNums[j].substring(3,7);
  }

  //Scan to get the # of words consisting of 7/3/4 letters
  //Eliminating space and apostrophe
  File words = new File("word_list.txt");
  int wordWidth7 = arrSize(words,7);
  int wordWidth3 = arrSize(words,3);
  int wordwidth4 = arrSize(words,4);

  //Copy these words to array
  //Eliminating space and apostrophe
  String[] wordList = copy(words,wordWidth7,7);
  String[] listOf3 = copy(words,wordWidth3,3);
  String[] listOf4 = copy(words,wordwidth4,4);

  char[][] representation = {{'A','B','C',' '},{'D','E','F',' '},
  {'G','H','I',' '},{'J','K','L',' '},{'M','N','O',' '},{'P','Q','R','S'},
  {'T','U','V',' '},{'W','X','Y','Z'}};

  for(int j=0;j<phoneNums.length;j++){
     System.out.println("TEL: "+phoneNums[j]);
     match(phoneNums[j],wordList,representation);
     match(first3[j],listOf3,representation);
     match(last4[j],listOf4,representation);
     System.out.println("--------");

  }

}

public static void match(String num,String[] words,char[][] rep){
  for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
     int matchFound=0;
     for(int j=0;j<words[i].length();j++){
        for(int column=0;column<4;column++){
           if(words[i].charAt(j)==rep[num.charAt(j)-48-2][column])
              matchFound++;
        }
     }
     if(matchFound==num.length())
        System.out.println(num+" : "+words[i]);
  }
}

public static int arrSize(File f, int length, String delimiter)
throws FileNotFoundException{
  int arrSize = 0;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(delimiter);
  while(in.hasNext()){
     String temp = in.next().trim();
     if(temp.length()==length){
        arrSize++;
     }
  }
  in.close();
  return arrSize;
}

public static int arrSize(File f, int length)
throws FileNotFoundException{
  int arrSize = 0;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
  while(in.hasNext()){
     String temp = in.next().trim().replace("'","");
     if(temp.length()==length){
        arrSize++;
     }
  }
  in.close();
  return arrSize;
} 

public static String[] copy(File f,int size,int length,String delimiter)
throws FileNotFoundException{
  Scanner in =  new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(delimiter);
  String[] list = new String[size];
  int i = 0;
  while(in.hasNext()){
     String tmp = in.next().trim();
     if(tmp.length()==length){
        list[i] = tmp;
        i++;
     }
  }
  in.close();
  return list;
}

public static String[] copy(File f,int size,int length)
throws FileNotFoundException{
  Scanner in =  new Scanner(f);
  String[] list = new String[size];
  int i = 0;
  while(in.hasNext()){
     String tmp = in.next().trim().replace("'","");
     if(tmp.length()==length){
        list[i] = tmp;
        i++;
     }
  }
  in.close();
  return list;
}
}
```

Comment: The exception tells you everything you need to know. In file Lab11.java at line 60, something has the index 2 which is out of range!

Comment: This tells you exactly where: `at Lab11.match(Lab11.java:60)`.  Go to that line and insert println statements to print out the index value and the length of the string.

Comment: Sounds like a school lab question...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add some print statements to help you debug. For example, before the line that is causing you problems:

```
if(words[i].charAt(j)==rep[num.charAt(j)-48-2][column])
```

you can try adding a statement such as:

```
System.out.println("The current num is: " + num);
```

If right before the program crashes you see:
"The current num is 12", then you know what is wrong because "12".charAt(2) will give you an out of bounds error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having some trouble parsing your code, but I think your problem is with the call to `num.charAt(j)` in your `match` function.

From your outer for loop, `j` is bounded above by `words[i].length()-1`, but there is nothing I can see that would promise that `num` is as long as `words[i]`; in other words, you have the potential for an out of bounds error.